# DRF: listview get works, detailview returns empty response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

please bear with me. I'm doing something silly but I don't know what.

I'm adapting/following the tutorial for [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/).

I'm using the serialization part of the tutorial to return users (list and detail views).

my listview (list all users) works perfectly.

my detailview doesn't. I can see that the serializer instance is being populated with a user for the detail view, however serializer.data is empty.

No error are returned, just an empty reply {}.

What am I doing wrong?

this works:

```
@csrf_exempt
def parentList(request):
    """
    List all parents or create a new parent
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        theseParents = PlatformUser.objects.all()
        serializer = parentSerializer(theseParents, many=True)
        return baseJSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

snippet from serializer:

```
class parentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlatformUser
        fields = ('pk', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'home_address_1', 'home_address_2', 'city', 'country', 'home_postcode', 'photo', 'overview')
```

this does not work (`serializer.data` is empty, but serializer is populated):

```
def parentDetails(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve or update a parent record
    """
    try:
        thisParent = PlatformUser.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    except thisParent.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer=parentSerializer(thisParent)
        return baseJSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your queryset is empty.

"Except DoesNotExists" is usless with filter. If no objects where selected thisParent will be empty queryset but not raise exception.

You need to rewrite your code like this if you want to get 404 on non existent object and pass object as queryset to serializer.

```
thisParent = PlatformUser.objects.filter(pk=pk)
if not thisParent.exists():
    return HttpResponse(status=404)
```

I would recommend you to use generic views from Rest Framework.

Comment: thanks - I don't think my queryset is empty.... for the last line in the code above `return baseJSONResponse(serializer.data)` I can see that `serializer` has a valid queryset (there's one user in the list as expected), however serializer.data is empty, and it shouldn't be... Also, i'm querying for a known user's primary key.

Comment: pass to serializer instance not queryset

    `serializer=parentSerializer(thisParent[0])`

or **better** rewrite your code to work with one object, not queryset

    `thisParent = PlatformUser.objects.get(pk=pk)`

Comment: that was the problem - I was sending it a queryset where it actually wanted an instance. could you please convert your comment ("pass to serializer....") to an answer and i'll mark that as accepted?